# Can I ask to reschedule an interview after being given an incorrect date?

Tags: recruitment

I was told over the phone my interview would be conducted on Monday. Since I needed to catch a flight to the interview location, I rescheduled my leave so my holiday would start on Tuesday. I have now been told my interview is on Wednesday. Can I ask to reschedule, and should I mention being given the wrong date?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**.  Odds are it's an honest mistake and they can reaccommodate, particularly if you're asking to do the interview earlier, which won't slow down things.

Of course, it's possible they can't change the date and you'll need to decide between going to the interview and going on holiday, but you have nothing to lose by checking.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, happened with me once. All you need to do is politely request them to postpone the interview by a week or some days as per your availability.

While the date of interview was changed I was informed that the person in charge to take my interview was really busy and had some deadlines to meet, so the change in the interview dates.

Anyways, I politely requested the person in charge to check if the interview can be scheduled next week, as I had some prior commitments as well. He understood and scheduled the interview when both of us were available making a win-win situation for both.