# Due to an interview mix-up, I have been rescheduled for a phone interview instead of a face-to-face interview. How can I use this to my advantage?

Tags: recruitment

I have been rescheduled for a phone interview instead of a face to face interview due to the interviewer mixing up the dates ([Can I ask to reschedule an interview after being given an incorrect date?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93387/can-i-ask-to-reschedule-an-interview-after-being-given-an-incorrect-date/93391#93391)). I have already done a phone interview with the company before. How can this second interview differ, and how can I use a phone interview to my advantage?

Comment: Don't! Call them and say "I'm sorry, you made a mistake, I should be having an in-person interview". If I were the interviewer, I'd notice I interviewed you by phone before and had asked for an in-person, I'd be very concerned that you didn't notice the mistake (or didn't care to correct it) and just went ahead and wasted my time back at Step 1.

Comment: You not clearing up the mixup might turn whatever "advantage" you think you might get out of it into a big failure. "What? That person knew there was a mixup and instead of helping correct the error, just took advantage of it for their personal gain? Why would we want to hire that person?" It speaks to your integrity as a person, or lack thereof.

Comment: Just instantly telephone them and say *"Oh, I already had a phone interview on blah date at blah PM with Mrs. Blah.  Is the next step a personal interview?"*  Nothing to it.

Comment: Please edit to make this an actual question, with a problem that can be solved. Questions asking for advice are not practical, answerable questions.

Comment: I think @RonBeyer and Ray are misunderstanding your situation because they didn't read your other question. My advice would be to avoid an in-depth phone interview. It's not easy to make a really good impression by phone and you will be competing with people that have had in person interviews. That being said since rescheduling flights is not always practical. See if they can interview you over Skype (or something else). Video conferencing is better than the phone. And no, you can't really take advantage of this change, you can only try to mitigate the damage that this change will create.

Comment: Also, we can not possibly tell you how this second phone interview will differ from the first one. We don't even know what type of job you're applying for. You should really give them a call now and ask them. PS: In earlier comment, I should have said "because rescheduling the flight and your leave from your current company is not really practical"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much that you can do to use this to your advantage. Lots of good comments to your question.

I recently went through a similar situation where a recruiting department at a company I interviewed with was using an automated system. I ended up receiving two incorrect, "Sorry, you didn't get the job" e-mails, along with incorrect interview dates and other mix-ups.

Close to half of my interactions with one recruiter were, "I'm confused. This e-mail says  and I was under the impression that  was supposed to happen. Can you clarify?" She was very accommodating and often apologized as she corrected the mistake.

I would suggest:

1. **Call them.** This gets a person on the line immediately, and you can have a back-and-forth conversation which will result in a resolution.
2. **Be courteous.** It's unclear where the mistake happened, but the goal here is to simply get everyone on the same page - not to assign blame or anything like that. Bend over backwards to be considerate and thankful during this conversation.
3. **Clarify expectations.** Use this opportunity to get an explanation of the whole interview process, so that you know what to expect for certain from this company.

In the end, I didn't get a job at that company. But I did manage to build good professional relationships with several of the HR staff there.  :)